# Can we set Firebase database node name from edittext?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Heyy Community...!

I want to create a node in firebase database each time with different node for different details  with different name from edittext in Android, means I want to put my database node name from edittext, but I'm unable to do this I have tried various methods but it is not working.
I want to show it like this.... this is my json file structure in firebase database,

```
  "Student name": {
    "Raj": {                <--- This node name I want ot create by getting text from edittext
      "name": "Raj",
      "Age": "12"
    },
    "Remo": {
      "name": "Remo",
      "Age": "21"
    }
```

I tried `String childname = editText11.getText().toString();`
and pass childname to database reference child but it is not working...
Please help me with this as soon as possible.
As I'm new here so if I type anything wrong here then let me know.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "but it is not working"  doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo My bad, actually it is not creating any node of text taken from input user, but somehow I managed to solve this problem, Thanks

Comment: What is the code that writes data to the database? Please add it to your question.